# print strings and variables in powershell for loop

Tags: powershell

I need to extract an alerts from rest api and sent it to a file with powershell

I was able to extract the alerts outputs looping the xml file:

```
    foreach ($c in $temp){$c.timeOfAlertFormatted,$c.parent,$c.child,$c.category,$c.servicePlanDisplayName,$c.message}
    Thu 09/19/2019 12:00:19 AM
    IL
    Servername
    Phase Failure
    Gold
    One or more source luns do not have a remote target specified/mapped.
    Wed 09/18/2019 02:18:25 PM
    IL
    Server2
    Phase Failure
    Gold
    One or more source luns do not have a remote target specified/mapped
```

I am new to PS , what i want to achieve is to add descriptive string

to each filed, i.e:

```
Time: Thu 09/19/2019 12:00:19 AM
Country: IL
Server: servername
```

etc ,the rest of the fields.

i tried :

```
foreach ($c in $temp){Write-Host "Time  : $($c.timeOfAlertFormatted)"}

Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : 
Time  : Thu 09/19/2019 12:00:19 AM
```

its printing empty "Time" fields

here is example of the xml:

Comment: Remove `Write-Host` and just leave `"Time  : $($c.timeOfAlertFormatted)"` and see if your results change. The timing of `Write-Host` within a script can't necessarily be relied upon as it does not use the output success stream.

Comment: its still prints the word "Time" multiple times
    foreach ($c in $temp) {"Time : $($c.timeOfAlertFormatted)"}
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : 
Time : Thu 09/19/2019 12:00:19 AM

Comment: As a diagnostic step, try adding ```write-host ($c | fl * | out-string)``` inside the ```foreach``` loop to dump a log of the entire ```$c``` object and see what the value of the ```timeOfAlertFormatted``` property is for each blank line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have already loaded the xml and filtered out the properties you need in a variable `$temp`.

I *think* what you want can be achieved by doing:

```
$temp | Select-Object @{Name = 'Time'; Expression = {$_.timeOfAlertFormatted}},
                      @{Name = 'Country'; Expression = {$_.parent}},
                      @{Name = 'ServerName'; Expression = {$_.child}},
                      Category,ServicePlanDisplayName, Message
```

The above should output something like

> ```
> Time                   : Thu 09/19/2019 12:00:19 AM
> Country                : IL
> ServerName             : Servername
> Category               : Phase Failure
> ServicePlanDisplayName : Gold
> Message                : One or more source luns do not have a remote target specified/mapped.
>
> Time                   : Wed 09/18/2019 02:18:25 PM
> Country                : IL
> ServerName             : Server2
> Category               : General Failure
> ServicePlanDisplayName : Gold
> Message                : One or more source luns do not have a remote target specified/mapped.
> ```

If your variable `$temp` is **NOT** what I suspect it to be, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58012544/edit) your question and show us the XML aswell as the code you use to extract the alerts from it.